# How to add values from an array as an object in a mutable dictionary with objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I'm in the beginning stages of learning how to code, and I'm trying to figure out a problem.  I created an array with 4 objects in it, then created an empty mutable dictionary.  And now I have to add the values in my array as objects in my mutable dictionary, and I can't figure out how to do it.  This is what I have come up with that is coming back with errors, I know its just simple syntax but I can't find the answer online.

```
NSArray *shoeOrder = @[@"Charles Smith", @(9.5), @"loafer", @"brown"];

NSMutableDictionary *shoeOrderDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 0] forKey: @"customer"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 1] forKey: @"size"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 2] forKey: @"style"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 3] forKey: @"color"];
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You got really close. Remove `@` from `setObject: @[` in each of the four lines. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask a question like this where you've tried something and the compiler "is coming back with errors", you should generally show the errors. It helps us help you.

That said, the issue in this case is extraneous "@" characters in the following lines:

```
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 0] forKey: @"customer"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 1] forKey: @"size"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 2] forKey: @"style"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 3] forKey: @"color"];
```

An expression like `[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 0]` is a message-send expression. It's sending the message `objectAtIndex:` with parameter `0` to the object `shoeOrder`. The expression does not require and should not have a leading `@`.

So, your code should have been:

```
[shoeOrderDict setObject: [shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 0] forKey: @"customer"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: [shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 1] forKey: @"size"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: [shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 2] forKey: @"style"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject: [shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 3] forKey: @"color"];
```

Comment: And note that each line could be rewritten using Objective-C literal syntax, for example: `shoeOrderDict["customer"] = shoeOrder[0]`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `shoeOrderDict[@"customer"] = shoeOrder[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

well, please remove @  in @[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 0].
....

```
[shoeOrderDict setObject:[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 0] forKey: @"customer"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject:[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 1] forKey: @"size"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject:[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 2] forKey: @"style"];
[shoeOrderDict setObject:[shoeOrder objectAtIndex: 3] forKey: @"color"];
```

....